# How to trigger on "appearance in viewport"

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a project made with Framework7. All content is programmed in one html file. The project contains several pages.

My goal is to update some spans (`[id^='Update']`) every second whenever they are visible but not when they are not visible on the screen. This will save traffic.

The problem I had with plugins like `jQuery.inview` or `jQuery.appear` is that they trigger on the first view but after this they always "see" the element even when I'm virtually on another page and the element is not visible to me.

### Edited

If I run `$.force_appear();` every second it updates the status - shouldn't this be done "always"?

However the new page just covers the first page - therefore the elements are not disappeared for the plugin even though I don't see them.

I hope this makes it clearer. Putting a demo online is too complex because I have to add the full framework.

Do you have any idea what I could do?

Comment: what have you tried till now. It would be good if you can create a demo of what you have and whats the issue.

Comment: It is difficult to put a demo up here but I found out more about what exactly happens. Please check the question again.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Check if element is visible after scrolling](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/487073/check-if-element-is-visible-after-scrolling)